# How to get a SObject instance from SearchKey?

Tags: python, tactic

How can I construct an instance of [`SObject`](https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC/blob/4.1.0.v02/src/pyasm/search/search.py#L2186) from an instance of [`SearchKey`](https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC/blob/4.1.0.v02/src/pyasm/search/search.py#L6313)?

I gone through almost all the methods of `SearchKey` but couldn't find any such function. All road went from `SObject` to `SearchKey` but none went the other way round.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SearchKey` class can't be initialized in the usual manner, it's just a:

> [convenience class for unique identifier for an sobject](https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC/blob/4.1.0.v02/src/pyasm/search/search.py#L6314)

Meaning the methods of this class are all either classmethods or staticmethods.

If one has the *search key* in the for of a string (`str`) then the *SObject* instance can be created using [`SObject.get_by_search_key`](https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC/blob/4.1.0.v02/src/pyasm/search/search.py#L6405).

E.g:

```
sobject = SearchKey.get_by_search_key("vfx/shot?project=vfx&code=S01_002")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:
`sobject = server.get_by_search_key("vfx/shot?project=vfx&code=S01_002")`
where server is the Tactic Server object

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.